# How can I convert a workweek double into a DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a workweek number (a number from 1 to 52) and I want to convert this into a date.

For example:

```
3.1 = 01/13/2014

22.4 = 05/29/2014
```

My company uses workweeks where Monday would be .1 and tuesday would be .2 etc (Saturday and Sunday are .6 and .7)

Anybody know of a plugin that does this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

**Update:**

Here's a visual of the calendar that I'm talking about. The workweek varies each year which may make this challenging. Thanks

[image]

Comment: It seems like a rather small problem.. What should the plugin do exactly? Just convert that string/number into a date?

Comment: I am sure you will have no problem finding an appropriate override of Convert.ToDateTime() for your needs.

Comment: How do your workweeks align to year start? Does the first workweek start on Jan 1 regardless of what day of week that is? Or does it start with the first Monday of the year?

Comment: If you need to convert 1.1 did you get 30 dec 2013?

Comment: Please see the update to my question. I've added a picture of the calendar. Thanks

Comment: Won't you have 53 weeks in some years?

Comment: @hatchet as you can see in the picture, the workweek starts on the first week on the year and isn't always Jan 1. In the above example, 1.1 would actually be 12/31/13

Comment: @hatchet I didn't think it would ever run over 53 since it would wrap to the next year

Comment: What does 1 in 13.1 mean? First day?

Comment: @GrantWinney correct me if I'm wrong: wouldn't 1.1 be 52.7?

Comment: @Edin 13.1 would signify the monday of that week. so 13.1 would be March 24th

Comment: 52 * 7 = 364. But a year is either 365 or 366 days long. Eventually, it would seem you'd need a year with 53 workweeks to catch up, otherwise, where do the extra day or two go, year after year after year?

Comment: @roshambo - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date to see what I mean about 53 weeks.

Comment: @hatchet I see what you mean. There would be a few times when this might occur. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute force approach, probably could be done better

Find the monday that precedes the first day of the year, this is the week 1.
Now multiply 7 for the converted number of weeks - 1 (we don't start from zero), add the number of days less 1 and pass the value to AddDays to find the exact date required

```
void Main()
{
    string k = "22.4";
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertWeekDay(k, 2014).ToString());
    k = "53.1";
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertWeekDay(k, 2014).ToString());
    k = "1.1";
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertWeekDay(k, 2015).ToString());
}

public DateTime ConvertWeekDay(string weekday, int year)
{
    int w; int d;
    string[] wd = weekday.Split(new char[] {'.'});
    w = int.Parse(wd[0]); d = int.Parse(wd[1]);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year,1,1);
    while(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
        dt = dt.AddDays(-1);

    dt = dt.AddDays(7 * (w - 1) + d - 1);
    return dt;
}
```

Notice that the 53.1 and 1.1 refers to the same day if you change the year.